# How to Manage git user?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu

I have a Plan , I am create some user on my server but I want give them restrict for access our Server like

1. that user can use git like (push,pull,clone,ect)
2. that user cannot login ssh
3. that user can be use sftp for manage project using ftp or sftp client, and cannot access(read,write,execute) filesystem directory . only project folder can they accesed.

I know git need ssh for do it git system.it's look weird question, it's possible using git like I mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you may use `git-shell` as a shell for git-only user (see `man git-shell`). Regarding sftp newer OpenSSH has ChrootDirectory directive, see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/SFTP#Chrooted_SFTP-only_Accounts